# What is the name for this sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

So, I work in industrial automation, and normally program with ladder logic. So its rather odd compared to what I would consider normal programing. Anyway I needed to sort a list of numbers from smallest to biggest. I was looking through sorting algorithms trying to find one I could easily implement using ladder logic. I was having a hard time, but after some thinking I came up with something that wasn't even on the Wikipedia list of sorting algorithms. Well,  It might be but I can't find it. I know this isn't very efficient sorting algorithm, but it does work. I want to know the name of it if it has one.

The basic version of this is, imagine an array of numbers. Take the first number in the list and compare it to all other numbers in the list, count the number of times that it is bigger than any of the other numbers. This accumulated value is the index number for where it goes in the output array. To place it in the array, check if there is already something written to that spot, if there is add one to the index and check again until there isn't anything in its spot. When the empty spot is found write it to the output array. Once you have done that to every number in the list you will have an output array with the same size as the input, but with it sorted smallest to biggest. I should note that this is assuming the language uses zero based indexing.

If this wasn't clear enough, I'm happy to elaborate further if needed.

Comment: How big (in terms of the number of bits) are the numbers that you are sorting?

Comment: 32 bits, and in the case where I implemented this sorting method, its a list of 50 numbers being sorted once every 24 hours

Comment: Since it looks like you can iterate over the array to count the rank of an element, implementing a bubble sort should be straightforward: walk the array in any direction looking at each pair of adjacent numbers; if the numbers are out of order, swap them; repeat the array walk 50 times.

Comment: Most [sorting algorithms with names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) order *in-place*. I don't know a name for this one.

Comment: You can skip the fussy placement step if you do the tiebreaking carefully, e.g., in Python, `for i, x_i in enumerate(input): output[sum(x <= x_i for x in input[:i]) + sum(x < x_i for x in input[i+1:])]=x_i`.

Answer (score -1):

I would say it's a worse version of [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort):

> It operates by counting the number of objects that possess distinct key values, and applying prefix sum on those counts to determine the positions of each key value in the output sequence

So it basically does the same thing you're doing: put each element in its final position by using counts. Counting sort uses an array to store the needed counts, you iterate the array to find them at each step for the current element.

I don't think there's a name for your exact algorithm.